# How to add id if there's custom validation rule when updating the record in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

How to add id in stud_num just like in email and username? the codes found in User Controller.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'first_name' => 'required|max:255|regex:/^([^0-9]*)$/',
            'middle_name' => 'nullable|max:255|regex:/^([^0-9]*)$/',
            'last_name' => 'required|max:255|regex:/^([^0-9]*)$/',
            'contact' => ['required', 'regex:/^(09|\+639)\d{9}$/'],
            'course' => 'required',
            'role_as' => 'required',
            'stud_num' => ['required', 'unique:users,stud_num', 'max:15', new StrMustContain('TG')],
            'username' => 'required|alpha_dash|unique:users,username,' . $id,
            'email' => 'required|email:rfc,dns|unique:users,email,' . $id
        ]);
                
        // codes for update    
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add id like email and username.

```
'stud_num' => ['required', 'unique:users,stud_num,'.$id, 'max:15', new StrMustContain('TG')]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write it like this:

```
'stud_num'=>['required',Rule::unique('users','stud_num')->ignore($id),'max:15',new StrMustContain('TG')]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).